# How to use Jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

From what I understand I need to write some of the PHP files and more myself to make this grid work with a sever and database. Is this true? And if so do you have any advice on where to start with this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Demo page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) is useful for getting started. It will show you how to put together basic grids, and there is PHP code there to show you how to retrieve data from a MySQL DB and return it to your grid. You can easily adapt this code to another DB (such as Postgres or SQL Server) as needed.

As you get going, the [documentation page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs) has a good set of API docs as a reference.